# How to Auto-Number Duplicate Rows Using Sequence Based on Multiple Duplicate Columns (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis

Trying to Create a Script for Auto-Numbering rows using Sequence Object where rows having the same values in columns [Surname, Birthdate, Sex] are categorized as Duplicates and each of these duplicates are respectively assigned the same 'Ext ID' which is assigned by Sequence Object........ 
And when new rows are run through the script, if it cant find matches based on the select columns, it should increment e.g R5 to R6 but if it can find matches in table, it should assign the 'Previously assigned' [Ext ID] of pre-existing match and not redundantly increment new [Ext ID]'

```
Ref Surname Firstname   Birthdate   Sex ExternalSource  Ext ID
1   AAA     AA          1/1/2000    M   Alpha           Null
2   BBB     BB          1/1/2001    F   Beta            Null
3   AAA     AA          1/1/2000    M   Beta            Null
4   CCC     CC          1/1/2003    M   Alpha           Null
5   BBB     BB          1/1/2001    F   Gamma           Null
6   DDD     DD          1/1/2004    M   Beta            Null
7   CCC     CC          1/1/2003    M   Alpha           Null
8   AAA     AA          1/1/2000    M   Gamma           Null
```

Such that the Script populates the column [Ext ID] accordingly as below table

```
Ref Surname Firstname   Birthdate   Sex ExternalSource  Ext ID
1   AAA     AA          1/1/2000    M   Alpha           R1
2   BBB     BB          1/1/2001    F   Beta            R2
3   AAA     AA          1/1/2000    M   Beta            R1
4   CCC     CC          1/1/2003    M   Alpha           R3
5   BBB     BB          1/1/2001    F   Gamma           R2
6   DDD     DD          1/1/2004    M   Beta            R4
7   CCC     CC          1/1/2003    M   Alpha           R3
8   AAA     AA          1/1/2000    M   Gamma           R1
```

Business Scenario> The table represents union of all records of clients in separate business applications and rows having the same surname, birthdate & Sex, are considered to be the same 'Customer' across these different Business Applications, so assigning the same value of [Ext ID] helps in categorizing these similar rows together such that [Ext ID] can be used externally to query & retrieve all records where these values are the same

---

**Further Clarification**
Assuming the 'Desired' script populates [EXT ID] of the 'FIRST' foundation Table loaded in database, please can someone create script for populating [EXT ID] in another table containing fresh set of new rows such that based on the same select columns [Surname, Birthdate, Sex], if matches are found between this 'NEW' table and the 'FIRST' foundation table,

```
Ref Surname Firstname   Birthdate   Sex ExternalSource  Ext ID
9   AAA     AA          1/1/2000    M   Alpha           Null
10  EEE     EE          1/1/2001    F   Beta            Null
11  AAA     AA          1/1/2000    M   Beta            Null
12  CCC     CC          1/1/2003    M   Alpha           Null
13  EEE     EE          1/1/2001    F   Gamma           Null
14  FFF     FF          1/1/2004    M   Beta            Null
15  CCC     CC          1/1/2003    M   Alpha           Null
16  AAA     AA          1/1/2000    M   Gamma           Null
```

the [EXT ID] assigned in the 'NEW' Table is retrieved from the [EXT ID] in the 'FIRST' Table but if there are no matches, the assigned [EXT ID] in the 'NEW' Table should continue from the end of the last assigned [EXT ID] in the 'FIRST' foundation Table e.g if [EXT ID] in 'FIRST' Table was R12, the [EXT ID] in the 'NEW' Table should be R13

```
Ref Surname Firstname   Birthdate   Sex ExternalSource  Ext ID
9   AAA     AA          1/1/2000    M   Alpha           R1
10  EEE     EE          1/1/2001    F   Beta            R5
11  AAA     AA          1/1/2000    M   Beta            R1
12  CCC     CC          1/1/2003    M   Alpha           R3
13  EEE     EE          1/1/2001    F   Gamma           R5
14  FFF     FF          1/1/2004    M   Beta            R6
15  CCC     CC          1/1/2003    M   Alpha           R3
16  AAA     AA          1/1/2000    M   Gamma           R1
```

Reason being that in reality, new fresh records will be aggregated from these Business Applications regularly of which it will be ideal to always reference the [EXT ID] in the 'FIRST' foundation table for 'NEW' tables since this column permanently serves as the external reference key to Source Business Applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173825.aspx) to give each of your unique combinations of `Surname`, `BirthDate` and `Sex` a unique number, then simply place this into an update statement to update your column:

```
UPDATE  t
SET     ExtID = NewExtID
FROM    (   SELECT  ExtID,
                    NewExtID = 'R' + CAST(DENSE_RANK() 
                                            OVER(ORDER BY Surname, Birthdate, Sex) 
                                        AS VARCHAR(10))
            FROM    dbo.YourTableName
        ) AS t;
```

**FULL WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #T;

CREATE TABLE #T
(   Ref INT, 
    Surname VARCHAR(50), 
    Firstname VARCHAR(50), 
    Birthdate DATE, 
    Sex CHAR(1), 
    ExternalSource VARCHAR(50), 
    ExtID VARCHAR(11)
);

INSERT #T (Ref, Surname, Firstname, Birthdate, Sex, ExternalSource)
VALUES
    (1, 'AAA', 'AA', '2000-01-01', 'M', 'Alpha'),
    (2, 'BBB', 'BB', '2001-01-01', 'F', 'Beta'),
    (3, 'AAA', 'AA', '2000-01-01', 'M', 'Beta'),
    (4, 'CCC', 'CC', '2003-01-01', 'M', 'Alpha'),
    (5, 'BBB', 'BB', '2001-01-01', 'F', 'Gamma'),
    (6, 'DDD', 'DD', '2004-01-01', 'M', 'Beta'),
    (7, 'CCC', 'CC', '2003-01-01', 'M', 'Alpha'),
    (8, 'AAA', 'AA', '2000-01-01', 'M', 'Gamma');

UPDATE  t
SET     ExtID = NewExtID
FROM    (   SELECT  ExtID,
                    NewExtID = 'R' + CAST(DENSE_RANK() 
                                            OVER(ORDER BY Surname, Birthdate, Sex) 
                                        AS VARCHAR(10))
            FROM    #T
        ) AS t;

SELECT  *
FROM    #T
ORDER BY Ref;
```

---

**ADDENDUM**

For maintaining this, I would suggest a slightly different approach, and have a separate table to maintain your ExtID, which would allow you to leverage an identity column:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Ext 
(
        ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
        Surname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        BirthDate DATE NOT NULL,
        Sex CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
        ExtID AS 'R' + CAST(ExtIntID AS VARCHAR(10)),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Ext__ID PRIMARY KEY (ID),
);
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UQ_Ext__Surname_Birthdate_Sex ON dbo.Ext (Surname, Birthdate, Sex);
```

Realistically, with a similar index on your base tables you probably don't need this ExtID column, you can just join to the above table to get the ExtID with not a huge performance hit, but on the off chance you did need to update the ExtID column you could use:

```
MERGE dbo.Ext AS e WITH (HOLDLOCK)
USING 
(   SELECT  DISTINCT Surname, Birthdate, Sex
    FROM    dbo.YourTable
) AS t
    ON t.Surname = e.Surname
    AND t.Birthdate = e.Birthdate
    AND t.Sex = e.Sex
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (Surname, Birthdate, Sex)
    VALUES (t.Surname, t.Birthdate, t.Sex);

UPDATE  t
SET     ExtID = r.ExtID
FROM    db.YourTable AS t
        INNER JOIN dbo.Ext AS e
            ON e.Surname = t.Surname
            AND e.Birthdate = t.Birthdate
            AND e.Sex = t.Sex
WHERE   t.ExtID IS NULL;
```

I have used `MERGE WITH (HOLDLOCK)` because this is the least vulnerable method I know of meeting a race condition, and getting unique constraint violations.

If all of this is not suitable, then I would still suggest as above (if possible) removing the `R` from the identifier, and making it just an integer. You can, if needed, create the text column as a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(   Ref INT, 
    Surname VARCHAR(50), 
    Firstname VARCHAR(50), 
    Birthdate DATE, 
    Sex CHAR(1), 
    ExternalSource VARCHAR(50), 
    ExtIntID INT,
    ExtID AS 'R' + CAST(ExtIntID AS VARCHAR(10))
);
```

This will just make getting the maximim easier, and would probably make other uses easier too.

Then, your update statement is fairly similar:

```
UPDATE  t
SET     ExtIntID = NewExtID
FROM    (   SELECT  t.ExtIntID,
                    NewExtID = CASE WHEN e.ExtIntID IS NOT NULL THEN e.ExtIntID
                                ELSE
                                    ISNULL(m.MaxID, 0) + 
                                    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY e.ExtIntID
                                                    ORDER BY t.Surname, t.Birthdate, t.Sex) 
                                END
            FROM    #T AS t
                    LEFT JOIN
                    (   SELECT  Surname, Birthdate, Sex, ExtIntID = MAX(ExtIntID)
                        FROM     #T
                        GROUP BY Surname, Birthdate, Sex
                    ) AS e
                        ON e.Surname = t.Surname
                        AND e.Birthdate = t.Birthdate
                        AND e.Sex = t.Sex
                    OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(ExtIntID) FROM #T) AS m (MaxID)
            WHERE   t.ExtIntID IS NULL              
        ) AS t;
```

If you can't make an `INT` column, again the update is pretty similar, you just need to mess around with formatting more:

```
UPDATE  t
SET     ExtID = NewExtID
FROM    (   SELECT  t.ExtID,
                    NewExtID = CASE WHEN e.ExtID IS NOT NULL THEN e.ExtID
                                ELSE
                                    'R' + 
                                    CAST(ISNULL(m.MaxID, 0) + 
                                        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY e.ExtID
                                                            ORDER BY t.Surname, t.Birthdate, t.Sex) 
                                        AS VARCHAR(10))
                                END
            FROM    #T AS t
                    LEFT JOIN
                    (   SELECT  Surname, Birthdate, Sex, ExtID = MAX(ExtID)
                        FROM     #T
                        GROUP BY Surname, Birthdate, Sex
                    ) AS e
                        ON e.Surname = t.Surname
                        AND e.Birthdate = t.Birthdate
                        AND e.Sex = t.Sex
                    OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(ExtID, 2, LEN(ExtID)))) FROM #T) AS m (MaxID)
            WHERE   t.ExtID IS NULL             
        ) AS t;
```

Comment: Thanks @GarethD, your script helps populate [EXT ID] when run for the FIRST TIME but would be grateful if you can provide script when run after this first time, will reference existing populated [EXT ID] & continue numbering pattern for new set of rows

Answer (score 1):

Use SELECT DISTINCT to get each person only once, and then use ROW_NUMBER() to create your IDs.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Surname, Birthdate, Sex, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by
 Surname,Birthdate, Sex) as RowNum
    FROM mytable
```

Then you can use this to assign those values using an UPDATE statement:

```
   UPDATE mytable
    SET [Ext ID] = 'R'+cast(RowNum as varchar)
    FROM
    mytable
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT Surname, Birthdate, Sex, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
ORDER by Surname,Birthdate, Sex) as RowNum
    FROM mytable) AS generateIds
    ON generateIds.Surname=mytable.Surname
    AND generateIds.Birthdate=mytable.Birthdate
    NAD generateIds.Sex=mytable.Sex
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at `DENSE_RANK()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx

Use it like this:

```
select 'R' + convert(varchar(100), dense_rank() over (order by Surname, Birthday, Sex)), ...
```